# Deleting content from a YAML file using Python while retaining the original structure

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

I have a YAML file.
I want to use my script to repo all "repository" instances that are not contained in a list of strings I have defined. My script:

```python
import yaml

core_repos = ["REPO1",
              "REPO2"]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    yml_file_name = "azure-pipelines.yml"
    with open(yml_file_name, 'r') as yml_file:
        yml_content = yaml.safe_load(yml_file)
    repositories = yml_content.get("resources", {}).get("repositories", [])
    filtered_repositories = [repo for repo in repositories if repo.get("repository") in core_repos]
    yml_content["resources"]["repositories"] = filtered_repositories

    with open(yml_file_name, 'w') as f:
        yaml.safe_dump(yml_content, f, default_flow_style=False)
```

The original:

```yaml
trigger:
  - release/test

pool:
  name: <REDACTED>-Linux
  demands:
    - agent.name -equals  <REDACTED>

# Overrides the value for Build.BuildNumber, which is used to name the artifact (ZIP file) that is produced
name: '$(Date:yyyyMMdd)T$(Hours)$(Minutes)$(Seconds)'

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: REPO1
      type: git
      ref: release/test
      name: <REDACTED>/REPO1
      trigger:
        branches:
          include:
            - release/test

    - repository: REPO2
      type: git
      ref: release/test
      name: <REDACTED>/REPO2
      trigger:
        branches:
          include:
            - release/test

    - repository: REPO3
      type: git
      ref: release/test
      name: <REDACTED>/REPO3
      trigger:
        branches:
          include:
            - release/test

    - repository: REPO4
      type: git
      ref: release/test
      name: <REDACTED>/REPO4
      trigger:
        branches:
          include:
            - release/test

stages:
  - stage: 'BuildAndUploadArtifact'
    jobs:
      - job:
        workspace:
          clean: all
        steps:
          - checkout: self
          # Core repos
          - checkout: REPO1
          - checkout: REPO2
          - checkout: REPO3
          - checkout: REPO4
```

After running the script my main goal seems to have been accomplished, but the output otherwise looks very wrong in several cases. The trigger ended up at the bottom and my comment is missing completely, to name a few things. What is causing this?

```yaml
name: $(Date:yyyyMMdd)T$(Hours)$(Minutes)$(Seconds)
pool:
  demands:
  - agent.name -equals  <REDACTED>
  name: <REDACTED>-Linux
resources:
  repositories:
  - name: <REDACTED>/REPO1
    ref: release/test
    repository: REPO1
    trigger:
      branches:
        include:
        - release/test
    type: git
  - name: <REDACTED>/REPO2
    ref: release/test
    repository: REPO2
    trigger:
      branches:
        include:
        - release/test
    type: git
stages:
- jobs:
  - job: null
    steps:
    - checkout: self
    - checkout: REPO1
    - checkout: REPO2
    - checkout: REPO3
    - checkout: REPO4
    workspace:
      clean: all
  stage: BuildAndUploadArtifact
trigger:
- release/test
```

Comment: Try [ruamel.yaml](https://pypi.org/project/ruamel.yaml/), it can preserve comments and more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it myself, this works using ruamel.yaml:

```python
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

core_repos = ["REPO1", "REPO2"]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    yml_file_name = "azure-pipelines.yml"

    yaml = YAML()
    yaml.preserve_quotes = True
    with open(yml_file_name, 'rb') as yml_file:
        yml_content = yaml.load(yml_file)

        repositories = yml_content.get("resources", {}).get("repositories", [])
        filtered_repositories = [repo for repo in repositories if repo.get("repository") in core_repos]
        yml_content["resources"]["repositories"] = filtered_repositories

    with open(yml_file_name, 'wb') as f:
        yaml.dump(yml_content, f)
```

Comment: Welcome to `ruamel.yaml` which, as you found out, tries to preserve the original as much as possible, including comments. It is generally better to open files with YAML documents as binary and have `ruamel.yaml` resolve the conversion. If you would use `pathlib.Path()` instances this is done for you (and it allows to drop the use of the with statement. The officially recommended extension for files containing YAML documents has been `.yaml` since at least September 2006, so please consider adapting the file naming (if azure handles that, microsoft is not the best wrt folliwing standards)

Comment: Interesting, why is it better to open it as binary?

Comment: If you open as binary, the parser can handle the intepretation of the bytes stream ( BOM(s) and non-ASCII characters) to unicode points. If not, Python will handle that and pass unicode points to the parser, but does that in a slightly different way and also making less information available to the parser. With the changes I am working on the second option also makes the parser slower if not opened as binary.

Answer (score -1):

As you are loading the original file, processing the resulting YAML object and then dumping it to a file with the same name, you should not expect a simple file edition, but simply a new YAML file that represents the structure you want, but not necessarily with the same formatting as the original file.

In your case, all keys end up ordered alphabetically, and the comment is ignored by the loading method, so it does not exist in the YAML object, and neither exists in the resulting file.

If you really want to make sure that YAML editions behave as if you were manually editing the file, you would need to treat the file as a regular txt and filter out the lines you want to remove. But that is a lot more regex and logic